# Automatically confirm JS confirm dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to sort of automate a process via Chrome Extension with JS, jQuery etc..

The problem comes when the confirm box appears and I am not able to confirm it without clicking the button myself...

I tried JS hijacking but it looks like it only works if the confirm method is called by my script but it does nothing when the method is called by the script of the original page.

I know that there are extensions that can remove all the popups so I am asking if there is a way to automatically confirm every confirm dialog...

( The extensions is intended to run for some time without me being on the computer so I cannot confirm it by myself )

**EDIT:**
I can't change the original behaviour ( neither anything on the website ) because it's not my website.. So I have to confirm the dialog without changing the original method..

Comment: Is the confirm dialog really needed then?

Comment: In a chrome extension, you should be able to manipulate the page's DOM, maybe you'll be able to modify its `confirm` function. Did you try executing something like `confirm = function () {return true;};` ? (or even further: adding a `<script>` tag to the original page ? Don't know if it would work...)

Comment: The problem is that I can't handle the confirm method.. it is fired by a script on the page and I am not able to change it.. the extension is intended to run on the website which is not done by me..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you inject the script containing the `window.confirm` override using  `"run_at": "document_end"`,

write this code in the file:

```
var g_original_alert = window.alert;

window.alert = function alert(msg) {

    var ignorable_messages = [
        "Your OTP  has been sent to your registered  mobile number. Please use the same for validating the transaction",
    ];

    if (ignorable_messages.indexOf(msg) !== -1)
    {
        console.log("Ignoring msg=" + msg);
        return;

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Cant' ignore msg=" + msg);
        g_original_alert(msg);
    }

}
```